# Oracle (10g) float(126) datatype conversion to IEEE754 binary64

Tags: c, oracle, oracle10g, type-conversion, ieee-754

Does anybody knows some details about how a floating point number is actually converted from **oracle 10g float(126) format** to **IEEE754 binary64 format** when loading this number from an oracle DB to a C program variable for example.

I have somebody who thinks that this is done by some simple rounding process but I would believe that the actual binary representation of both format in memory is probably completely different.

However I could not find a lot of details about the actual binary representation of oracle float(p) type. **Does anybody have some information about how this actual conversion process works ?**

I guess the actual number loaded in the C variable might even differ depending on the driver used but I would appreciate if somebody has some information on this topic.

Thanks